# Скачать файл с оригинальным названием

Tags: java, файлы, download

как правильно скачать файл с ресурса с оригинальным названием и расширением?
Знаю что у `File` есть метод `getName()`, как подставить название файла вместо "`w4.pdf`"?
Может я неправильный путь решения выбрал?

```
 String url = "https://onedrive.live.com/download?resid=72571393D4771099!7571&authkey=!AKRZuNSbUxV2I1I&ithint=file%2cpdf";
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;
    try {
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        System.out.println("code response : " + httpURLConnection.getResponseCode());

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("E:\\w4.pdf")));
        int c;
        while ((c = bis.read()) != -1) {
            bos.write(c);
        }
        bos.close();
        bis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: А как сам файл называется?

Comment: неизвестно, название файла может быть какое угодно

Comment: посмотрите что содержит заголовок ответа "Content-Disposition" (`httpURLConnection.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition")`). Там должно быть что-то вроде `"attachment; filename=filename.ext"`, откуда уже можно вынуть содержимое регуляркой/substring. Для имен, содержащих только ascii символы все просто, для других [несколько сложнее](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266#section-5)

Comment: `"Content-Disposition"` выдает null если ссылка прямая на файл, к примеру `https://site.com/img/image.jpg`. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: если ссылка как в основном вопросе, то все ок, `"Content-Disposition"` содержит `Content-Disposition : attachment; filename*=UTF-8''%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba2.doc`, но тут уже вопрос выковырять название файла и транслитирировать в латиницу

Answer (score -2):

Наугад,но пробовал переделать строчку так: `BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("E:\\"+bis.toString())));` Уже сам проверил,не пашет.А вообще все это проще с [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)